# How to display the posts and news in front page?

Tags: blog, frontpage

I'm trying to display the two recent posts in a bloc I created in a front page of my website.

index.html:

```
<div id="blog">
<h1>
Post title 1
</h1>
<p>
Description
</p>
<button>
Read More
</button>
<h1>
Post title 2
</h1>
<p>
Description
</p>
<button>
Read More
</button>
</div>
```

I want that the `Post title 1` and `Description` of each post will be updated automatically when the admin add a new post and the recent post will be displayed on the front page.
I installed the [insert php](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/) to add php code in a html page, then I wrote this snippet of code to test if I'm able to get the posts from the blog:

```
[insert_php]
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo "test successful";
    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
[/insert_php]
```

But I got `Sorry, no posts were found` however I had some posts in the blog page of my website.How can I fix that to display the latest recent posts in my front page?

Comment: Is it WordPress related? Are using a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement this program into your html page:

```
<ul>
<?php

global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ul>
```